# extract words from a string by matching string pattern

Tags: java, string

Is there any easy way to extract word by comparing with string pattern in java.

```
input
pattern: what do you know about <topic1> and <topic2>
string : what do you know about cricket and football

output
cricket, football
```

Comment: try it with regex and capturing groups

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("what do you know about (.*) and (.*)"; // in line you create a pattern to which you are checking other Strings
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToCompare); // in this line you decide that you want to check stringToCompare if it matches the given pattern
while(m.find()) { // this loop prints only captured groups if match was found
    System.out.println(m.group(1)) +" " + m.group(2));
}
```

In the `Pattern` there are capture groups (in brackets) , and their order starts from 1, counting their occurence from left to right. In `while` loop you decide only to print these groups to console.

In the following line you don't need to pass reference to variable, you may also want to pass `String` literal to `Matcher` instead of reference to `String` variable:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher("what do you know about cricket and football");
```

Above line works fine too.